# HttpRequestMessage/StreamContent, empty Stream on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I want to post a stream to a HTTP server (hosted by OWINHost), see code snippet below.
It works fine when I transfer a String with StringContent.
However if I want to transfer a MemoryStream with StreamContent, the stream received on the server side is empty (I verified that the MemoryStream is correct by deserializing it on client side for test purposes).
What am I doing wrong?

Client-side:

```
...
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Configuration.ServiceBaseAddress);

// this works fine!
//request.Content = new StringContent("This is a test!!");

request.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
...
```

Server-side:

```
public class Startup {
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.Run(async context => 
    {
      var stream = new MemoryStream();
      await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
      stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

      // this works fine when I send StringContent
      //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
      //String str = reader.ReadToEnd();

      // when I send StreamContent the stream object is empty
      IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      ServiceRequest requestTest = (ServiceRequest)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

      context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
      await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you already written something to the stream? I don't see that happening in the first code fragment, but maybe you do it already. Just a check.

Comment: Yes I did write an object into the stream. Like I said for test purposes I deserialized the stream on client-side and the object was restored. I omitted the code for clarity.

Comment: I use Windows 7 and Microsoft.Owin and OwinHost 3.0, it runs in debug mode in Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: Looks like you do it correct. Maybe try to find out where the bytes of your stream are lost. This can be done by WireShark, a low level network protocol analyser. You can see if the packet that is sent contains the stream data. WireShark is free, but not a beginnerstool. https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Answer (score 5):

I forgot to include:

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

on the client-side.